# Separate String Lines using StreamReader | VB.net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to make my own checklist app. I am using a ListView object to display each checklist item. I can add individual items to the object. I don't know how to save the ListView items on exit and then load them in on startup. (I tried using My.Settings, but it doesn't work.)

My solution was to make an import/export system using .txt files to store data. They are formatted like this:

Item1

Item2

Item3

When I import them, it all shows as one long item in ListView. I am using the code below.

```
Private Sub ChooseFileButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChooseFileButton.Click
    If ImportFileDialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim fileReader As String
        fileReader =
        My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(ImportFileDialog.FileName)
        ImportFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = True

        ChecklistObject.Items.Add(fileReader)
    End If
End Sub
```

If anyone knows how to write individual items on their own line in a text file, that would be great too.

EDIT: Exporting doesn't work either. Using code below:

```
    Private Sub ExportButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExportButton.Click
    ExportFileDialog.Filter = "Keklist Save|*.kek"
    If ExportFileDialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK _
  Then
        ChecklistObject.Items.Item()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example code you are only adding one item to the list view so it will only show the one line.

You could use `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` to read all the lines of the file into a string array.

```
Private Sub ChooseFileButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChooseFileButton.Click
    If ImportFileDialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim path As String = ImportFileDialog.FileName
        Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
        ImportFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = True
        For Each line in lines
            ChecklistObject.Items.Add(line)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, thanks for actually using the button names and everything. I know many people just use the defaults like "Button1".